# Swift: permanent variable change through global files

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, swift, properties

I am working in between **three files**: `Menu.swift`, `Main.swift` and `Game.swift`.

In my **Main.swift**, I define the *variable* `swipeNumber`:

```
class Main {
    var swipeNumber: Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            println("The new swipe number is \(swipeNumber)")
        }
    }
}
```

*N.B. It is **in a class** so that I can **reference the variable from other files**, and the **didSet property observer will function**.*

As you can see, its **initial value** (*I think*) is `0`.

Then, in my **Menu.swift**, I *retrieve the information* from the **Main class** in *Main.swift*.

```
let main = Main()
```

I then have **three buttons**, which will, *on touch*, **change the `swipeNumber` variable**, based on which button was pressed.

```
class Menu: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func pressedThreeSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
        main.swipeNumber = 3
    }

    @IBAction func pressedFiveSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
        main.swipeNumber = 5
    }

    @IBAction func pressedTenSwipes(sender: AnyObject) {
        main.swipeNumber = 10
    }

    //...

}
```

When I run the program, *my property observer appears to work*, **printing messages** such as:

```
The new swipe number is 3
The new swipe number is 5
The new swipe number is 10
```

And **in the Game class**, (*for troubleshooting purposes)*, I have another property observer, **checking the integer  of the variable `swipeNumber`** when the button `test` is pressed:

```
class Game: UIView {

    let main = Main()

        func didMoveToView(view: UIView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        println("now")
        println("\(main.swipeNumber)"
        //Nothing happens here, suggesting that didMoveToView is failing

    }

    @IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("\(main.swipeNumber)")
    }

}
```

My `func test` **prints a number**, but sadly that number is **not 3, 5, or 10**. **It's `0`.**

*I think that the problem lies with my variable in **Main.swift***, however I am not sure.

Any advice or 'fixes', whether quick or lengthy, would be very greatly appreciated.

***Thank you,***

**Will**

Answer (score 2):

You have different instances of your class `Main`, and they each carry a different value for the same properties.

You should try the Singleton pattern (see e.g. [here](http://code.martinrue.com/posts/the-singleton-pattern-in-swift) or [here](https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton)).

Comment: This seems like a good idea, do you think you could possibly edit your answer to use my variables and my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Main(), you are creating a new object...emphasis on NEW.  It has no knowledge of what you've done to other objects of the same type.  If you want to use the same object in different places, you need to make it a parameter and pass it into methods rather than creating a different object.

Comment: How do I make something into a parameter? Any help you could give  me (with my variables) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how your Menu and Game objects are being created  (i.e. your program structure).  One possibility would be to give Game an initializer like `init(withMain mainObject:Main) {/* Save mainObject to use inside this Game */}` and pass the object you had been using before.